# IMAP server responds with "BAD..." error to "LIST..." after similar "LIST" command completes successfully

Tags: email, imap, mailbox, protocol

I'm getting a `BAD...` error when running a `LIST` command against an IMAP server that I'm not understanding and could use some help with.  I run almost an identical command just prior to it to list the *root mailboxes* and have no problem, but then as I begin to iterate over those mailboxes and try to list their child mailboxes, I get the error.  The odd thing is that even though the first returned line from the IMAP server is the `BAD...` response, it still fulfills the rest of the query as if nothing was wrong?!?!

To start off, you'll need to know the `namespace` details of the server in question...

```
NAMESPACE

Array
(
    [0] => * NAMESPACE (("" ".")) NIL NIL
)
```

This server uses an empty *root namespace*, and a period (`.`) for the mailbox *delimiter*.

Here's the command I'm using for the *root* list...

```
LIST "" "%" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN SPECIAL-USE STATUS (MESSAGES UNSEEN))
```

For which I get the expected response...

```
Array
(
    [0] => * LIST (\Subscribed \HasChildren) "." Archives
    [1] => * STATUS Archives (MESSAGES 0 UNSEEN 0)
    ...
)
```

I should mention that all of the `RETURN` meta capabilities were established from an earlier `CAPABILITIES` request.

So based on the results, I begin to iterate over them to get the *child mailboxes*, with the first one being `Archives`.  The syntax I'm using is based almost identically to that outlined in the [RFC 3501 #6.3.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.8) examples under `LIST`...

```
LIST "Archives." "%" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN SPECIAL-USE STATUS (MESSAGES UNSEEN))
```

I would expect it to list all of the child mailboxes relative to the `Archives` mailbox, which it does, however it first lists a `BAD...` response...

```
Array
(
    [0] => * BAD Error in IMAP command : Unknown command (0.000 + 0.000 secs).
    [1] => * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren) "." Archives.2017
    [2] => * STATUS Archives.2017 (MESSAGES 0 UNSEEN 0)
    [3] => * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren) "." Archives.2016
    [4] => * STATUS Archives.2016 (MESSAGES 192 UNSEEN 0)
    [5] => * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren) "." Archives.2019
    [6] => * STATUS Archives.2019 (MESSAGES 1 UNSEEN 0)
)
```

First, I don't understand what I've done wrong, and further, the `BAD...` error is not referencing a specific command like it should, so I really don't have anything to go on here.  Second, if it's failing, then why is it still completing the rest of the request?

Could really use some help, thanks!

---

**EDIT 1:** I'm getting this same unexplained error from two different IMAP servers I'm testing against, and they're both exhibiting the same behaviour... returning the correct records, but not before including a `BAD...` error first.  So it must be something in the syntax of my `LIST...` requests, but I feel like I'm using the same examples that the RFC defines, so I'm at a loss.